# No se puede exportar BD en Phpmyadmin

Tags: base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, ubuntu, virtualbox

estoy realizando una base de datos en una máquina virtual de Ubuntu en VitualBox utilizando phpmyadmin, y al ir al exportarla me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por qué puede ser?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Es un _error de red_? (como mencionaron [hace poco](/q/523354)). Buscando en internet, al parecer está sucediendo con la versiones más recientes de phpmyadmin.

Comment: Podría ser un mundo de cosas, desde la instalación del linux en la maquina virtual, permisos, direccionamientos, incompatibilidad , que este mal la versión del phpmyadmin,  No se la finalidad de instalar ubuntu en una maquina virtual, quizás podrías intentar instalar xampp que te proporciona el soporte para mysql

Comment: Hola! Necesito realizar un proyecto en una máquina virtual de Ubuntu, por eso la he creado con VirtualBox, en ella he instalado xampp y a partir de ahí es cuando he utilizado phpmyadmin para crear la BD. Estoy teniendo problemas con la máquina en sí, así que debe de ser algo de la creación de la misma.